# Is it possible to run services with limited privileges?

Tags: networking, server, security

I have a home server with some web and database services running (nodejs, postgres, neo4j). Later I intend to add a vpn server, so I will be able to access the services from the office. As far as I know if somebody manages to badly crack the nodejs and/or the databases, he can possibly run shell commands with superuser privileges. Is it possible to prevent this somehow, for example by adding an user with limited privileges, which can start this services by boot up? I am not experienced with Linux, but I try to make the system as safe as possible. Any help appreciated.

(I already thought of docker as sandbox, but I don't feel it production ready. For example there is the [PID 1 zombie reaping problem](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/), which I think should be fixed by docker developers and not by the community with some init process workaround. Another argument against docker, that the server has very limited resources, so it would be better not to use virtual machines.)

Comment: "As far as I know if somebody manages to badly crack the nodejs and/or the databases" Ehm, you intend to run these as root? "he can possibly run shell commands with superuser privileges" If you answer that 1st one with "no", how do you see this happening? :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Currently there is only a root user, and maybe pgsql create a postgres user. I am not sure how to run these services as a different user, since they start by boot and I am new to Linux. Is this possible? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

[Generally best practice is to run services as a non-root user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394984/best-practice-to-run-linux-service-as-a-different-user#395013)
On my Ubuntu system, installing neo4j defaulted to running neo4j as a user name neo4j.  If you are install from the official repos, using apt-get, this **should** be an non issue.  Those users should not be in any groups that can gain root privileges like wheel, suers or admin. It should not be able to use sudo.

But ...

If you must (or chose to) write your own startup script or do an install not based on an official repo, and it runs a root, create a user and use "sudo -u command" to not run it as root.

Here is how to create a user: http://www.debianadmin.com/users-and-groups-administration-in-linux.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My main problem is with nodejs and not with the databases. I am aware that almost every database has a dedicated user by default.